Migrating a web site from shared cPanel to unmanaged Ubuntu 22.04 vps and not able to successfully import an sql file
I got an unmanaged VPS from Hostinger a week ago and am trying to host a few websites on the server. I have to say here that I am quite new to Ubuntu 22.04 with FASTPANEL.
I have migrated the files and databases from the old server to this new one, except for one SQL file. The specifications of the old server are:

I tried to import this SQL file from one of the websites into phpMyAdmin without success. I believe it is not because of the size of the file. I had successfully imported a larger file of an almost identical site (in a different language). The specifications of the new server are:

The error thrown by phpMyAdmin when importing is:
Error

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during the analysis.

A symbol name was expected! (near ")" at position 206)
At least one column definition was expected. (near ")" at position 206)
SQL query: Copy

-- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Stand-in structure for view `m6K_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate` -- (See below for the actual view) -- CREATE TABLE `m6K_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate` ( );

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8

I believe there are no errors in the above-specified lines.
I also tried to import it via Hostinger browser terminal:

cd /var/www/fastuser/data/www/en.beentee.net
mysql -u beentee -f -p enbeentee < mgls_enbeent.sql

The error thrown by the Hostinger browser terminal is:

I even tried to create an upload folder for phpMyAdmin with the following commands though I still do not know if the file can be imported this way:
sudo find / -type d  -name phpmyadmin

mkdir -p /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload
mkdir -p /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save
chmod a+w /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload
chmod a+w /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save

gedit /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

cd /usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin
sudo nano config.inc.php

But the last two commands did not work:
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/usr/share/fastpanel2-phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/save';


Reply by kos:

You switched from MariaDB to MySQL; they are mostly compatible, but
they're not a full drop-in replacement for each other; please post the
output of sed -n '2496323,2496333p' </path/to/problematic/sql/file

mgl:
Please find the output below:
sed -n '2496323,2496333p' </var/www/fastuser/data/www/en.beentee.net/mgls_enbeent.sql


Reply by kos:
Well, lines 2496323 and 2496324 make up a definition of an empty table, which is not valid in MySQL. I'm not sure what that would mean in MariaDB. You may try and remove that table definition (sed '2496323,2496324d' </path/to/problematic/sql/file >/path/to/new/file -> this will create a new file which you will then have to import), however, I'm not sure if it'd imply the application using the database. Maybe you should try and see if MariaDB allows for a full MySQL-compatible export option, and export the DB again.
mgl:
I'll try to export a compatible file first. Please help me choose one or two from this drop-down menu:

Reply by kos:
The highest compatible MySQL version seems to be 4... Which is prehistoric. I would try that, unless you've done that already the first time around.
mgl:
I was able to reduce the errors to one error using the compatibility modes:
Using DB2
mgl:
Then, I checked the tables with a database cleaner. You are right. The table is empty. I excluded the table from export and imported the resultant sql file successfully. And waiting for the website to propagate. I thank you for your help!

You switched from MariaDB to MySQL; they are mostly compatible, but they're not a full drop-in replacement for each other; please post the output of sed -n '2496323,2496333p' </path/to/problematic/sql/file

Please find the output at the end of the question above. I couldn't insert an image here.

Well line 2496323 and 2496324 make up a definition of a table with no fields, which is not valid in MySQL. I'm not sure what that would mean in MariaDB. You may try and remove that table definition (sed '2496323,2496324d' </path/to/problematic/sql/file >/path/to/new/file -> this will create a new file which you will then have to import), however I'm not sure if it'd have an effect on the application using the database. Maybe you should try and see if MariaDB comes with a full MySQL-compatible export option, and export the DB again. I can't make sense of a table with no fields, but who knows.

I'll try to export a compatible file first. Please help me choose one or two from the drop-down menu. The image is at the end of the question above.

The highest compatible MySQL version seems to be 4... Which is prehistoric. I would try that, unless you've done that already the first time around.

I was able to reduce the errors to one error using the compatibility modes (DB2).

Then, I checked the tables with a database cleaner. You are right. The table is empty. I excluded the table from export and imported the resultant sql file successfully. And waiting for the website to propagate. I thank you for your help!

I'm glad you figured it out!
